# Highcharts '0' padding in line chart

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using highcharts, and would like to implement the [following graph][image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TEYX.png]

I'm using 'categories' property for the dates, and the 'data' array for the values.

Unless I remove the ''categories' field, I have
a redundant padding

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5uR3.png]

What I have already tried, and didn't work?

1. Set 'maxPadding : 0' for xAxis
2. Set 'showFirstLabel : false"
3. Set 'step: 5'

How can I define this '0' padding?

Comment: Can you share some of your code? or where it is on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following option:

```
series: {
  pointPlacement: 'on'
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n8gd4qy6/

**API Reference**:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointPlacement